# *ngif Not working after first click. Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-forms, web-frontend

What I want to Achieve is that I have a Select field in angular6 on the basis of the selected value I want to hide and display another div.

Here is the code.

```
 <div class="form-group">
          <label for="servicePriviledges">Managed</label>
          <select type="text" class="form-control" id="managedServiceInfo" name="managedInfo" [(ngModel)]="managed">
            <option value="false">False</option>
            <option value="true">True</option>
          </select>
           <br>
        </div>

<div class="form-group" *ngIf="managed">
          <label for="managerType" >Manager Type</label>
          <select type="text" aria-hidden="false" class="form-control" id="managerType" name="managerType">
            <option value="false">False</option>
            <option value="true">True</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

*ngIf does make an impact when I switch it for the first time but not after that. the change is not detected.

I have even tried setting up the visibility attribute of style as well as [hidden] directive but got the same result.

I have even tried giving an on change method but no change in result.

version information:

```
"@angular/core": "^6.1.6",
"@angular/forms": "^6.1.6",
```

Both these controls are under a form 'ngForm'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach is to attach `[ngValue]` directive for every option.

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="managedServiceInfo" name="managedInfo" [(ngModel)]="managed">
    <option [ngValue]="false">False</option>
    <option [ngValue]="true">True</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

`managed` will have a string value of `'true'` or `'false'` update ngIf like this

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="managed === 'true'">
 ...
 </div>
```

or you can use ngValue so managed will have a boolean value of true , false

```
 <select type="text" class="form-control" name="managedInfo" [(ngModel)]="managed">
   <option [ngValue]="false">False</option>
   <option [ngValue]="true">True</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: We are thinking the same thing for second approach. Anyway, +1.